# BitTorrent programs killing networking - Broadcom wireless

Tags: networking, 14.04, broadcom, bittorrent

This started happening after I did a fresh install of 14.04 (previously I was on 13.04). When ever I launch a BitTorrent client my DNS very quickly stops responding, and then the network connection itself stops working completely (to the point of disconnecting and failing to see the network again).

It works just fine on my wired connection, but with wireless (which is a Broadcom; I followed the steps here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218898 to get it working) then it craps out.

Edit: I have verified that I have the correct drivers installed. My output is

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1673] (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
```

and I have linux-firmware-nonfree installed.

Answer (score 1):

Bittorrent can stress any server or router because it tends to use many connections at once: more than some cheap consumer routers can handle.  The easy solution is to reduce the number of maximum connections your bittorrent software uses in the software itself.  Try various numbers but less than 400 is a reasonable number that should work - as a troubleshooting measure you can try less than 128 in a pinch but that may hurt download speed.

(Good routers allow ~4000 or more simultaneous connections, often ~16000 or more, bad/cheap routers may limit to ~500 or even ~128 in extreme cases - and that is shared by all users of your network, even cellphones on your wifi).

That said, the multiple connections that a bittorrent client uses should not put stress on a *DNS* server.  It is possible that the DNS problems you are experiencing may just be a side effect of problems with your router handling that many connections, in which case this isn't a DNS issue but DNS problems is just a symptom.  For example, DNS uses a connectionless protocol and such protocols suffer when there is packet loss, which may occur in a router that is overloaded in other ways.

Another strange issue is that you say it works fine over a wired connection but not wireless.  If they are going through the same router either way (eg. the access point and the router is the same device, or if it's a separate access point it has NAT disabled / doesn't use the WAN port) then it should work the same.  Have you done any other testing to see whether there are general problems with wifi on that same PC?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried reducing the maximum connections to 64 yet it still happened exactly as before. Prior to changing that setting, it was set at 500 connections maximum.

I strongly suspect at this point that it is related to my Broadcom wireless card, although I don't know exactly what I need to change at this point. It worked in 13.04.